# setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener is not provided

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

I want to display strings in `TexView` as a result of image analysis.
I am using CametaX(`androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-rc01`) for the camera function.

It should be able to update the `TextView` every image analysis, but it can't access the TextView from the `ImageAnalysis.setAnalyzer process`.

So, I tried to update the TextView every time the preview is updated.

```
PreviewConfig pConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder().build();
  Preview preview = new Preview(pConfig);
  preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(
    output -> {
      ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(ResultString[0]);
});
```

However, `setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener` is not provided in the latest CameraX preview.

How can I change the string(TextCiew) displayed on the screen sequentially?
Or, it should implement original Lifecycle Class? How?

I've implemented following implementations

```
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-rc01"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.0-rc01"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha20"
```

Is it needs any other implementations?

I am using Java, but there are very few Java samples.
It would be great if you could show me a concrete solution using Java.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement following implementations

```
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.0-alpha05"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-alpha05"
```